# Missing `rbc-now` class

Tags: reactjs, react-big-calendar

I want to style only the date number of the current date, but the `rbc-now` class is missing from the `rbc-current` element. If I style by `rbc-current`, then all the dates in every month are styled, for example: 9th August, 9th September, 9th Ocotber etc.

The demo works correctly.

I'm using the latest stable version of the component.

Do you have any idea? :)

Answer (score 0):

In order to use a attribute with a hyphen using React's JSX syntax you need to change all hyphen names to camelcase such as...

```
<MyComponent rbcCurrent="testing" />
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. There is no rbcCurrent prop in React big calendar .